# Displaying Comments Jinja2-Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

I'm writing a blog in Google App Engine using Python and Jinja2. I have a GQL Table for my blogposts and one for all the comments. Each record in the common table has a blogpost_id column so that I know which blogpost they are linked to. I use the query 'SELECT * from BLOGPOSTS' and pass this to my render function. Then in my HTML Template there is a for-loop that prints out all my blogposts. This goes pretty smooth. In the permalink of a blogpost, it's easy to print the comments because I know the blogpost_id so I can just query the comments table against it and print them out.

Whereas, On the front page I want to display the first two comments of every blogpost right below it. but I am not able to come up with a solution for printing out comments below the blogposts on my frontpage because I don't know how to pass the comments of a particular blogpost to my render function. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than just passing the result of your GQL query containing the blogposts to your template, why not pass a list of dictionaries that maps the blog post to it's two most recent comments?

Something like this might work (although is likely not the most efficient way to do it):

```
posts = GqlQuery("SELECT * from BLOGPOSTS")
posts_and_comments = []
for post in posts:
    two_comments = GqlQuery("SELECT * from COMMENTS WHERE blogpost_id = :1 ORDER BY age LIMIT 2", post.blogpost_id)
    current_post = {post: two_comments}
    posts_and_comments.append(current_post)
```

Then you could pass `posts_and_comments` into your template, and iterate through that in whatever way you please.

Also, rather then checking via the `blogpost_id`, you may want to look into [ancestor queries instead](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Ancestor_Filters), and set the ancestor of each comment to it's parent post.

Comment: can you give an example with ancestor queries and how you'd set up the database for that to work.

Comment: That's kind of a subject for another question, so I'd recommend reading some of the Google docs on ancestor queries. But basically, when you create a new comment entity, you could do something like this: `parent=db.Key.from_path(datastore_model_name,post_id)`. This is put in the parameters when you create the entity. This organizes things nicely, and gives several benefits (including quick queries to find comments with the same parent entity).